# disable specific dates in specific month of every year jquery datepicker in jquery the date should be from database

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

disable specific dates in specific month of every year using datepicker in jquery.
the date should be from database.

For Example:
disable the date of auguest 15 th of every year and the date auguest-15th is getting from database with the formate of string.

Answer (score 1):

For disabling more than one date for all years In a calendar ,

Use:

return [!( (day ==15  && month == 8) ll (day ==2  && month == 10) ll (day ==26  && month == 1) ) , " "  ];

Answer (score 0):

U can use beforeShowDay, example :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var day = date.getUTCDate();
    var month = date.getUTCMonth();
    return [(day != 15 ) && (motnh != 8)];
   }
})​​​​​;​
```